# How to know if exit nodes are the bottleneck

Tags: relays, exit-relays

I've read that the exit nodes are the bottleneck of the tor network, and I've also read the opposite. Did the answer change at some point or is it changing often?

What is the best way to determine if the exit nodes are the bottlenecks *right now* and/or just "recently"?

Ultimately I'm wondering if I'm wasting my time by adding non-exit nodes if they're not needed, or if I'd be wasting my time trying to safely set up a new exit node when a new non-exit would help just as much.

Comment: If bottlenecks are happening, I would wager that they are for very short periods of time. The Tor Metrics page suggests that, although exit nodes are less common, there is still plenty of bandwidth in the network: https://metrics.torproject.org/bandwidth-flags.html